# Xamarin Binding fuction as ImageSource inside a Listview with Databinding

Tags: image, listview, xamarin, binding

I'm trying to visualize the state of an object, called `MinRepresentation`, in the ListView below.

I want to bind the function `ImageSource stateImage(MinRepresentationState state)`, where i handover the state and get back the Imagesource.

My Problem is, accsessing the function and passing the parameter via xaml.

`Visible Orders` is an Collection of `MinRepresentation` each includes `State`

```xml
<ListView HasUnevenRows="True" SelectionMode="Single" ItemsSource="{Binding VisibleOrders}" ItemSelected="OnListViewItemSelected" ItemTapped="OnListViewItemTapped">

***OTHER STUFF***

<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Padding= "0,5,0,5" BackgroundColor="#CC3F6E3F">

<Image Source="{Binding stateImage(State)" Margin="10,0,0,0" />

<Label Text="{Binding Id, StringFormat='ID: [{0}]'}" FontSize="Small" Margin="5,0,0,0" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="#FFFFFF"/>

</StackLayout>

***OTHER STUFF***

</ListView>
```

```cs
public ImageSource stateImage(MinRepresentationState state)
        {

            switch (state)
            {
                case MinRepresentationState.Assigned:
                    return ImageSource.FromResource("state_assigned.png");
            }
        }
```

Comment: you can only bind to public properties, not methods

Comment: Any Idea how i can work around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [IValueConverter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/converters#the-ivalueconverter-interface) to achieve that. Create an `IValueConverter` class and place your logic code there:

```
public class StateToImageConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        MinRepresentationState representationState = (MinRepresentationState)value;
        if (representationState == MinRepresentationState.Assigned)
        {
            return "state_assigned.png";
        }
        return "otherImage.png";
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Then consume it in XAML like:

```
<!--Define it in resources-->
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <local:StateToImageConverter x:Key="StateToImageConverter"/>
</ContentPage.Resources>

<!--Use converter-->
<Image Source="{Binding State, Converter={StaticResource StateToImageConverter}}" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
```

Comment: This ist working so far, the only problem im facing now is, that the Pictures doesnt load.

Thanks in Advance for all the help :)

Error:
```[0:] Could not load image named: {0}: state_new.png
[0:] FileImageSourceHandler: Could not find image or image file was invalid: File: state_new.png```

Comment: I tried:

                   ```C#
 return ImageSource.FromResource("state_new.png");
return "state_new.png";
 return "Images/state_new.png"; ```

Comment: @Erstingo There's no need to return an image source, using string is ok: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=windows

Comment: `[0:] Could not load image named: {0}: state_new.png`
Maybe because the `StateToImageConverter` class isnt in the same namespace as the images?

Comment: @Erstingo Where did you place your image? Please refer to the doc I post above: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=windows. Read the section about how to use the local image on each platform.

Comment: Thanks its working, but i just had to delete the bin/obj folder once ;)

Comment: @Erstingo Maybe caches problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can only bind to public properties.  Create a StateImage property on your model

```
public string StateImage 
{
  get {
    switch (State)
    {
      case MinRepresentationState.Assigned:
        return "state_assigned.png";
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a `DataTrigger` to set the image in your XAML

```
<Image Source="state_default.png" Margin="10,0,0,0">
    <Image.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger TargetType="Image" Binding="{Binding State}" Value="Assigned">
            <Setter Property="Source" Value="state_assigned.png" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Image.Triggers>
</Image>
```

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/triggers#data